# Vertical Range Slider in Plotly time series?

Tags: r, plotly

For example, reproduce by running:

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)
setDefaults(getSymbols,src='google')
getSymbols('AAPL',from="2010-01-01",to=Sys.Date())
df <- data.frame(Date = index(AAPL), coredata(AAPL))
colnames(df)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
          high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
p
```

Now this plot does not have a *vertical* slider/range selector like plotly scatterplots do (say to zoom on a price and time range rather than just a time range as now). How to add one to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by changing `xaxis` in  `layout`. Using piece of code from [example](https://moderndata.plot.ly/native-support-for-candlestick-charts-in-plotly-and-r/):

```
rangeselectorlist = list(
  x = 0, y = 0.9,
  bgcolor = "#0099cc",
  font = list(color = "white"),

  buttons = list(
    list(count = 1, label = "reset", step = "all"),
    list(count = 1, label = "1yr", step = "year", stepmode = "backward"),
    list(count = 3, label = "3 mo", step = "month", stepmode = "backward"),
    list(count = 1, label = "1 mo", step = "month", stepmode = "backward"),
    list(step = "all")
  )
)
```

and adding to

```
p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
          high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart",
     xaxis = list(rangeslider = list(visible = F),
     rangeselector = rangeselectorlist) )
p
```

adds vertical slider/range selector.